# How does "Save as Live Template..." work in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I select the following code:

```
    //This is for debugging Live Template
    try {

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```

then click Tools > Save as Live Template...

Nothing happens.  Could anyone offer a tip on how to select a snippet and save as a live template?

Comment: That works for me (using IntelliJ IDEA) - the dialog is opened. Check if there are any errors in log (Help | Show log in...) after trying this. Also make sure you are selecting the source code, located in your project source directory.

Comment: @Andrey  Thank you. I have just realized that there was indent when I tried it many times in many different ways.  I have edited my post to reflect this. It works as soon as I remove the indent.

Comment: IDE version used? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174644 (looks like it's the case) is fixed for 2017.3 (not sure what AS version it will be .. but try comparing build numbers).

Comment: @LazyOne Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Comment: @Hong Well .. that ticket is fixed for 172/173.xxx branches. No idea on what the AS version it might be in. Possible workaround -- make selection with no leading whitespace .. and edit created Live Template after if required.

Comment: @LazyOne You are right that it works as long as there is no leading space.  Could you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174644 -- this looks like your case.

It's fixed for 172/173.xxx branches -- no idea what Android Studio version it would be.

---

**Workaround for now** -- make selection with no leading whitespace .. and edit created Live Template after if required.